# How to remove mat-option padding

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-material

The expected result should look like this :

[image: Expected result]

And my array Html and CSS looks like this

HTML:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="collaborateurs">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef class="vueListeTh"> Collaborateurs </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="vueListeTd">
          <mat-select placeholder={{element.collaborateurs[0].nom}} class="collabSelect">
            <ng-container *ngFor="let collaborateur of element.collaborateurs">
              <mat-option [ngSwitch]="collaborateur.acces">
                <div *ngSwitchCase="'COMPLETED'" class="selectCollaborateurCompleted" >
                    {{collaborateur.nom}}
                </div>
                <div *ngSwitchCase="'PREVIEW'" class="selectCollaborateurCompleted" >
                    {{collaborateur.nom}}
                </div>
                <div *ngSwitchCase="'EDITION'" class="selectCollaborateurEdition" >
                    {{collaborateur.nom}}
                </div>
                <div *ngSwitchCase="'WAITING'" class="selectCollaborateurWaiting" >
                    {{collaborateur.nom}}
                </div>
                <div *ngSwitchDefault>
                    {{collaborateur.nom}}
                </div>
              </mat-option>
            </ng-container>
          </mat-select>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
```

CSS :

```
.vueListeTh.mat-header-cell, .vueListeTd {
padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
.vueListeTh.mat-header-cell:first-of-type,
.vueListeTd.mat-cell:first-of-type {
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.vueListeTh.mat-header-cell:last-of-type,
.vueListeTd.mat-cell:last-of-type {
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.selectCollaborateurCompleted {
  padding-left: 4px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #8cc83c;
}

.selectCollaborateurEdition {
  padding-left: 4px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffff00;
}

.selectCollaborateurWaiting {
  padding-left: 4px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}
```

I have tried to change .mat-option attribute to padding: none, but it doesn't affect the outside padding of the text div. .ng-star-inserted and mat-select-content don't work either.

[image]

Comment: to override the css add !important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try either

```
.mat-option {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

or

```
:host .mat-option {
  padding: 0;
}
```

The latter applies the style to parent elements too.

Comment: First one works as I want ! I can even define a class in the <mat-option> to style it. I see that I was mssing the !important.